# PHP - Outbound connections to remote servers are failing

Tags: linux, networking, php

I have setup a blog although, it appears any connections going outbound (to remote server) are being blocked. My firewall is set to allow everything through (iptables) and this problem appears to be occurring only with php applications. I remember there was an option in PHP.ini along time ago that could cause this - I think it was called "safe-mode" but according to my php.ini file it is not enabled - does anyone have any ideas?

My php.ini:
http://pastebin.com/esABTwGE

Comment: Is there an error message? Have you tried it with `display_errors` set to `on`?

Answer (score 0):

What function are you using to make this connection?  Functions like `include()` and `file_get_contents()` can take URLs but rely on the [fopen wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php).

You have `allow_url_include = Off` in your php.ini which will stop `include()` and `require()` and similar from retrieving URLs.

Functions like `curl_exec()` do not rely on fopen wrappers but can have their own issues.  Failed DNS lookups will cause a failed connection.

You currently have `log_errors = On` and `error_log = /var/log/php_errors.log`.  Have a look in that file for your errors.  Add any errors you find to your question.

Don't turn `display_errors = On` on a production system. This is a security risk.